# What's the best practise to increase the side paddings in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to increase the paddings on the sides of the page in Bootstrap. On the official site I didn't see any topic about it.

[image]

What is the best practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS for the first and last columns in a `row` like this..

```
[class*='col-']:first-child {
  padding-left:0;
}

[class*='col-']:last-child {
  padding-right:0;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/ywLU4iKl08

Answer (score 1):

On the official site they are just simply added by: `padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;`

If you don't want to use this, you can always use percentages (padding-left:2%;) or you can use offset classes like: `col-md-offset-1`

Don't forget, you can always change the source code, so you can change the columns number.